Filter based on date between 2 dates
**Update 15/07/2024
I have now managed to resolve this issue with the following method;
InDateRange = 
var _rangeStart=FIRSTDATE('Fiscal Year report'[Date])
var _rangeEnd=LASTDATE('Fiscal Year report'[Date])
return 
if(
    SELECTEDVALUE('Lease Information'[Term Start Date])<=_rangeEnd
    &&
    SELECTEDVALUE('Lease Information'[End Condition Date])>=_rangeStart
    &&
    SELECTEDVALUE('Lease Information'[End Condition Date])<>BLANK(),
1,0)

I created a new column 'End Condition Date' to ensure all rows contained an end date, given an active contract doesn't have an end date but should be listed in my results.
This, on first glance, looks to be working.
Original Text
I am trying to filter a list of contracts (table 1), based on whether or not the date I select from my calendar slicer (table 2) is between the 'Start' and 'End' dates (Table 1). For example, if I have a contract that started 01/01/1998 and then ended on 31/12/2020 I want to see the details each time I select a year in my slicer.
In this example the contract would be listed in my visualization table when I select any of the years between 1998 - 2020 in my slicer, but only once if I select multiple years in my slicer.
Full disclosure, I am still on a Power BI learning journey, I have tried to use the following (which I found here) to identify if the contract should be 'Included' or 'Excluded', which created an additional column.
Date Included = 
IF (
    FIRSTNONBLANK ( 'Table 1'[Term Start Date], 1 ) <= MAX ( 'Fiscal Year report'[Date]) &&
    FIRSTNONBLANK( 'Table 1'[End Condition Date], 1 ) >= MIN ( 'Fiscal Year report'[Date]),
    "Include",
    "Exclude"
) 

I applied this as a visualization filter so that when I select a fiscal year in my slicer (based on Table 2) it would list the relevant 'Include' contracts. It works in so far as it will list all contracts with a 'Start' date within the desired Fiscal year but does not list it for any year thereafter, until the contract ends. It doesn't seem to be registering the 'End' date and I am unsure how to establish a relationship between 'End' date to Table 2 (Fiscal), as 'Start' is the active relationship between the 2. I did try but got ambiguous error message.
Relationship between tables
Table and Slicer
Thanks.

You will need to capture the Min and Max dates from the slicer, and then remove the context of the slicer to count/check the contracts.
For example:
Contract count = 
  var startDate = MIN('Fiscal Year report'[Date])
  var endDate = MAX('Fiscal Year report'[Date])

  var result =
    CALCULATE(
      COUNTROWS('Lease Information').
      REMOVEFILTERS('Fiscal Year report'),
      'Lease Information'[Term Start Date] <= endDate &&
      'Lease Information'[Term EndDate] >= startDate
    )
   
  return result // or COALESCE(result, 0)

This measure will return the count of contracts which you would use a Visual Filter, and with the added benefit of using it in other visualizations.
Notes:

startDate and endDate gets the min/max dates of what is selected in the slicer.
REMOVEFILTERS(...) removes the context of slicer (effectively ignoring the relationship.


Hi Sam,
Many thanks for the above. I have added this to my model but unfortunately it now doesn't seem to register the end date. It is counting rows where my end date is prior to the selected Start date in my slicer. It has remedied the issue I had where the returned results was only rows => to the start date. It is the exclusion of rows where the end date is less than the selected start date that is presenting issues. This maybe a result of my 'Lease Information' end date having no relationship to the 'Fiscal Year report' but I am struggling with establishing that relationship.

Could you share a sample PBIX (via OneDrive, Google Drive etc... link)?

Hi Sam
It doesn't look like I can, admin restrictions at my place of work. I did share a link but when opened, it wasn't available to edit. I'll have another try. Thanks.

Is End Condition Date the same as Term End Date? Could you update your question with a few sample rows of your Lease Information table (in markdown format, not image)?

Hi Sam,
I created the End Condition Date to account for Blanks in my Term End Date, so theoretically they are the same but the End Condition Date holds a date 12 months on from today if the Term End Date is blank. I now seem to have it working by utilising an effective set of IF conditions to provide a Filter. I'd like to share it but when I do it just pastes it as a string.

Updated my original question with my found solution.
